# Android: using fragments programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

For some reasons I can't use xml layout files.

But I need to create a tablet android app.

I decided to use fragments.

I want to create the same layout that this xml generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment class="com.example.ItemsList"
            android:id="@+id/items_list" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/item_details" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But I have problems with adding fragments to my linearLayout:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(createUI());
    }

    private View createUI() {
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        layout.setId(0x101);
        {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(0x101, new ItemsList());
            fragmentTransaction.add(0x101, new ItemDetails());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        return layout;
    }
```

Actually I can't even create LinearLayout with two identical fragments:

```
            ...
            fragmentTransaction.add(0x101, new ItemsList());
            fragmentTransaction.add(0x101, new ItemsList());
            ...
```

Please help

Btw I can't figure out why do we need to declare "FrameLayout" for itemDetails Fragment but "fragment" is enough for itemsList ListFragment?

UPD:

To do so one should just add third param:

```
            ...
            fragmentTransaction.add(0x101, new ItemsList(), "uniqueTag1");
            fragmentTransaction.add(0x101, new ItemsList(), "uniqueTag2");
            ...
```

Default value for the tag parameter is null, so I was trying to create two different elements with identical ids. Thanks to p-lo for his comment.

Comment: Have you tried the [Fragments example on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)?

Comment: Of course I did. Repeat: my problem is that I can't use xml files at all!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I interpreted your question as that the layout wouldn't inflate. So essentially you want a pure Java implementation of that layout, correct?

Comment: Yep. At least I found a solution that worked for me=) it's on this page, later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the solution.

(the better way was added to the question. Thanks, p-lo)

If you want to place more than one fragment on activity you should create layouts for each fragment:

```
    private View createUI() {
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


        LinearLayout innerLayout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        innerLayout1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        innerLayout1.setId(ITEMS_LIST_ID);
        {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(ITEMS_LIST_ID, new ItemsList());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        layout.addView(innerLayout1);

        LinearLayout innerLayout2 = new LinearLayout(this);
        innerLayout2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        innerLayout2.setId(ITEM_DETAILS_ID);
        {
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(ITEM_DETAILS_ID, new ItemDetails());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
        layout.addView(innerLayout2);

        return layout;


    }
```

Comment: The nested layouts are not needed here if the two fragments are added with third arguments, each being a unique string tag. The default value for the third argument is null. The code above is trying to add two fragments with the same null tag. That works when they are added to their own layouts.

Comment: What is ITEM_DETAILS_ID and ITEMS_LIST_ID here ?

Comment: It's a pretty old question. But as far as I remember these are any ids you'd like. like 1 or 2. When you add elements in xml - you usually use automatic id generation (like R.id.newElement), but when you add new element programmatically - you should create your own unique ids

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing is the LayoutInflator.  See this example from an activity:

```
private void createPolicyTable() {

    if (customerInfo.getPolicies() == null || customerInfo.getPolicies().isEmpty()) {
        Log.v(TAG, "no policies were found.");
        return;
    }

    LinearLayout policyTable = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.manage_my_policy_policy_table);      
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    for(int i = 0; i < customerInfo.getPolicies().size(); i++) {
        Policy policy = customerInfo.getPolicies().get(i);

        LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.policy_table_row, null);

        ImageView type = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.policy_table_row_type);

        if (policy instanceof PersonalVehiclePolicy) {
            type.setImageResource(R.drawable.auto_policy);
        }
        else if (policy instanceof HomeownersPolicy) {
            type.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_policy);
        }

        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.policy_table_row_policy_number)).setText(policy.getPolicyNumber());
        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.policy_table_row_amount_due)).setText(policy.getAmountDue());
        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.policy_table_row_due_date)).setText(policy.getDueDate());

        row.setOnClickListener(createPolicyDetailsOnClickListener(policy));

        policyTable.addView(row);

    }

}
```

and the layout that's being inflated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" style="@style/ListItem">

    <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:paddingBottom="5dp">
            <TextView android:text="@string/type_label" style="@style/RowLabel" />

            <ImageView android:id="@+id/policy_table_row_type" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />         
            <TextView style="@style/RowLabel" android:text="@string/policy_num_label" 
              android:paddingRight="5dp" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/policy_table_row_policy_number" style="@style/DefaultText" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:paddingBottom="5dp">
            <TextView style="@style/RowLabel" android:text="@string/due_label" android:paddingRight="5dp" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/policy_table_row_amount_due" style="@style/DefaultText" android:paddingRight="5dp" />
            <TextView style="@style/RowLabel" android:text="@string/on_lc" android:paddingRight="5dp" />
            <TextView android:id="@+id/policy_table_row_due_date" style="@style/DefaultText" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. But Inflater is used to "inflate" from the layout xml, am I right? As I said before I'm not able to use xml files - I have to generate everything programmatically. There must be a solution, I guess=)

Comment: @leshka:  You mean it's literally a requirement thatyou generate everything programmatically?  That's not really ideal...at all.  I thought when you said you couldn't use XML, you meant you were having trouble getting it working?

Comment: Yes. It was a requirement=) Not ideal, I know=)