# Dynamic Fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is it possible to create fragments dynamically to generate a layout containing multiple fragments something like in a grid view. Currently, i m only able to load multiple fragments provided my layout has those number of fixed fragments.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

[android using fragments programmatically][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871666/android-using-fragments-programmatically

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely! Check out the Android Developers guide to Fragments. Be sure the see the second bullet point here, as well as the "Performing Fragment Transactions" section: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Adding

Additionally you can see your options for managing Fragments in this class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html